# Touch Sensor and Potentiometer - Need some help

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, potentiometer, capacitors

I'm using an Arduino Nano with a capacitive touch sensor and a potentiometer. I'm trying to get my code to differentiate between three different program states.

- One is when my touch sensor is NOT being touched.
- Two is when my touch sensor IS being touched.
- And three is when my touch sensor is being touched AND a potentiometer is being moved at the same time.

I'm having trouble picking up the second program state, when I'm simply touching the fader but not moving the potentiometer. Program state 1 works great, but program state 3 activates even when there's no data coming in from the potentioeter.

Here's the code. And ideas?

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>
#define rxPin 4
#define txPin 1

const byte touchSend = 2;
const byte touchReceive = 7;

byte minimumCp = 200; // Raise if the fader is too sensitive (0-16383)

bool touched = false; //Is the fader currently being touched?

CapacitiveSensor touchSensor = CapacitiveSensor(touchReceive, touchSend);

void setup() {
  touchSensor.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT );
  pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(57600);
}
void loop() {
  int faderPos = analogRead(A7);
  int lastfaderValue;
  int totalCp =  touchSensor.capacitiveSensor(30);
  if (totalCp <= minimumCp) {  // Not Touching Fader
      touched = false;
      Serial.println("Not Touching Fader"); 
      delay(15);}
  if ((faderPos == lastfaderValue) && (totalCp > minimumCp)) { // Touching Fader
      touched = true; 
      Serial.println("Touching Fader, NOT Moving"); 
      delay(15);}
  if ((faderPos != lastfaderValue) && (totalCp > minimumCp)) { // Touching Fader and Moving
      touched = true; 
      Serial.println("Touching Fader, Moving"); 
      delay(15);}
  lastfaderValue = faderPos; }
```

Comment: Your `lastfaderValue` is always equal to `faderPos`.

Comment: Every time you enter `loop` you’re comparing the pot input with an arbitrary value that you *think* is the last pot value, but since it’s local to `loop`, it isn’t. You may have not intended that to be a local variable. I’d add that you’ll probably want a minimum pot delta as well since simultaneous reads may not report the same value even if it’s not being moved.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

I had the lastfaderValue integer in the wrong spot. It works when I put it at the beginning of the code (before the setup).

I also added a tolerance, so that the potentiometer can still fluctuate slightly when I'm not touching it.

Works well now.